# cookie not being set with phonegap filetransfer upload Response

Tags: android, cookies, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap v1.7 FileTransfer to upload a file to my server and receive the http response from the server. I am testing on Android 4.0.3 google apis emulator.

After i call a filetransfer upload from the client app - my webservice receives the file sets a cookie(php setcookie - secure,http only) and then returns a http response to the client app - the client app receives the correct response as FileUploadResult object but the cookie is never set which i can see in my subsequent calls to the servers.

In terms of sending the cookie to the webservice the FT upload works just fine. But FT upload does not seem to receive a set cookie header (or does not set the cookie).

Other wise for other interactions with JQM ajax calls I can see the cookie setting works just fine and i can see this because: 
1) i see the response headers in the command line curl 
2) for any previous and subsequent ajax calls from the client app the setcookie works just fine. 
3) and i am pretty sure after a few hours of testing and logs that it is the phonegap File Transfer upload that is not setting the cookie but the response data contents are just fine.

Is this a known issue? if yes any workarounds? please help!